# Restart failed jobs of a specific worker in resque

Tags: ruby-on-rails, resque

I have about 5 queues running in my application. I am not interested in restarting all the failed jobs. I just want to restart the failed jobs that belong to one worker.

I am using Resque with rails. I see an option to "Retry failed Jobs" in /resque page.

But, How do I restart the failed jobs that belong to one worker?

Comment: Have you looked at `resque-web`

Answer (score 0):

I have found those articles about your question [Resque: how to requeue failed jobs](http://ariejan.net/2010/08/23/resque-how-to-requeue-failed-jobs/) and [Resque: automatically kill stuck workers and retry failed jobs](http://vitobotta.com/resque-automatically-kill-stuck-workers-retry-failed-jobs)

Comment: (Resque::Failure.count-1).downto(0).each { |i| Resque::Failure.requeue(i) }