# Does resque automatically retries failed jobs?

Tags: resque, resque-scheduler

Or is there a config somewhere which would accept number of retries. Any inputs would be appreciated. I saw this link [Restart failed jobs of a specific worker in resque](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18780191/restart-failed-jobs-of-a-specific-worker-in-resque) and have an idea on how to retry jobs manually. I am looking for making this step automated.

Answer (score 1):

You can use resque failure hooks which is called whenever is job is failed.

You can either override this method or use some plugin to do so.
once jobs is failed log and retry it from here only.

Code from resque code base, file: resque-1.27.1/lib/resque/job.rb

```
 # Given an exception object, hands off the needed parameters to
# the Failure module.
def fail(exception)
  begin
    run_failure_hooks(exception)
  rescue Exception => e
    raise e
  ensure
    Failure.create \
      :payload   => payload,
      :exception => exception,
      :worker    => worker,
      :queue     => queue
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

No, Resque doesn't have a built-in retry functionality.

You can use the plugin [`resque-retry`](https://github.com/lantins/resque-retry) or if you're already using [ActiveJob with Resque](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48551550/2771889) you can use the native [`retry_on`](https://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveJob/Exceptions/ClassMethods.html#method-i-retry_on) feature.

Note that `resque-retry` doesn't seem to work with ActiveJob so it's either-or.